# Certain Fonts used in HTML looks different than google fonts

Tags: html, css, fonts, google-font-api, google-fonts

In google docs, for `Montserrat` font they have the word `January` looking like this (which is the same as the design I want):[image]

In my code, I use the same format but what I see is a totally different font in my browser. This is my code:

```
<div class="event-date">January</div>

.event-date {
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}
```

And this is what I see in the browser (totally different than google fonts):

[image]

Is there a way to fix it to look like google fonts?

Comment: Make sure to link the font to your code, check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must first link the font (ideally in the `head` tag), because this font is not part of the operating system. When the web browser can't find the font, it uses default font for the operating system.

```
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or you can also import it in your CSS file.

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100&display=swap');
```

Check the Google Fonts CSS API documentation for more info: https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/css2